# Python XPath Result displaying only []

Tags: python, xpath, libxml2

Hey I have just started to use Python recently and I want to use it with a bit of xPath, the thing is when I print the result of the query I only get [] and I don't know why =S

```
    import libxml2, urllib


doc = libxml2.parseDoc(urllib.urlopen("http://www.domain.com/").read())
result = doc.xpathEval("//th//td[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2) and parent::*)]//a")

if result != []:
    print result
elif result == "":
    print "null"
else:
    print result

doc.freeDoc()
```

I get no error whatsoever just a []. What could it be? also is there any better documentation for libxml2 than the one [here](http://xmlsoft.org/html/index.html) since I find it reaaaally confusing =S

---

**Edit**

I changed the code, so now I get more than the [] I get the following output which should be related to the non-validity of the html I'm trying to parse (but it's not mine so I can't modify it). Any ideas on to how to tell Python to be more forgiving with that fact?

> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag tr line
>   209
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag tbody
>   line 208
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag table
>   line 207
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag input
>   line 206
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag input
>   line 205
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag form line
>   204
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag table
>   line 99
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag div line
>   98
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag body line
>   96
>
> ^ Entity: line 3552: parser error :
>   Premature end of data in tag html line
>   3
>
> ^ Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\libxml2.py",
>   line 1263, in parseDoc
>       if ret is None:raise parserError('xmlParseDoc() failed')
>   libxml2.parserError: xmlParseDoc()
>   failed

It's actually a longer list but there's no point in placing it all here, since all errors are due to invalid html.

Comment: What elements are you trying to select? Maybe that will help us figure out the problem, if we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're trying to select any link inside any td inside any th. Are you sure about the th?

Comment: ...and, yes, the libxml2 docs are really horrible :-(

Comment: Actually I know that the select works. Using the Firefox Plugin for xPath I get the titles of a list of items in a table. the Expression is 100% working

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your XPath doesn't select any elements.  For example, you are looking for td's inside th's, but those elements are peers, and shouldn't nest.

Why do you say `(count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2` instead of `count(preceding-sibling::*) = 1`?

If you use a simpler XPath, do you get the results you expect?

Comment: for that matter, why not `position()=2`?

Comment: I may have complicated myself a bit haha, but the thing is this is the only expression that managed to return me EVERY link inside a table. Otherwise I would just get one or two.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing th and tr?  Change your th to tr.

Comment: no I'm not, again the xPath expression works perfectly, I just can't get anything more than a [] when trying to print it. The odd thing is, the same thin in PHP works just fine, as well as in JAVA

Comment: XPath beginning `//th//td` will select only `td` elements that are descendants of `th` elements.  Unless your XHTML has table headers that contain tables, that XPath's not going to return anything.

Comment: Yes it IS returning the links inside the table I've tested it quite extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: Where does all that unnecessary complexity in your XPath come from? This:

```
//th//td[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 2) and parent::*)]//a
```

is equivalent to:

```
//th//td[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 1)]//a
```

and very probably even to:

```
//th/td[2]//a
```